# How to achieve sudo su - <user> and run all command in ansible

Tags: ansible

I have an ssh access to the box but to run certain commands I need to do sudo su -  and enter the password. Then I can run all the commands under that user.

How can i achieve this ansible. I tried become and sudo nothing worked for me.

Can someone provide me a working example?

Comment: did you try `become_method: su`?

Comment: yes no luck with that

Comment: I think error message from debug output (set ANSIBLE_DEBUG=1) will be helpful here.

Comment: This was the error coming  {"failed": true, "msg": "Timeout (12s) waiting for privilege escalation prompt: "}

Answer (score 4):

this is what working for me ...

```
become: yes
become_method: sudo
become_user: myuser
become_flags: 'su -c'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ansible uses [the `become` directive](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/become.html) to control privilege escalation.

If you're using `sudo su -`, you're using `sudo` to raise your privileges (and `su -` merely launches an interactive shell).  `become_method` should be set to "sudo".

Since you aren't using password-less sudo, you need to tell Ansible that you will be supplying a password.  You can do this in a config file with `ansible_become_pass`, but a much more secure method is to invoke ansible with `--ask-become-pass`.