# ansible: how to become a passwordless user

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to achieve the following with ansible

1. create a user without a password

> ```
> adduser test <-- ok and works on linux machine and works with ansible
> ```

2. change to user test

> su test     <-- works on linux machine, but fails with ansible. I get
> incorrect password message

3. copy a file from location1 to location2 as a test user and change a file content.

> cp loc1/testfile.txt loc2/testfile.txt && echo "hello" > testfile.txt

> ```
> ---
> - name: This is a hello-world example
>   hosts: all
>   tasks:
>     - name: create a passwordless test user
>       action: user name=test state=present
>       become: yes
>       become_user: root
>
>     - name: Create a file called '/tmp/testfile.txt' with the content 'hello' using test user.
>       copy:
>         content: hello
>         dest: /tmp/testfile.txt
>         owner: test
>         group: test
>       become_user: test
> ```

primary conditions:

at a moment of execution the file `testfile.txt` is already created on linux machine and has a group root and user root. I want to override the file and assign different user and group.

I've tried various combination, including

> ```
>       copy:
>         content: hello
>         dest: /tmp/testfile.txt
>         owner: test
>         group: test
>       become: yes
>       become_user: test
> ```

> ```
>       copy:
>         content: hello
>         dest: /tmp/testfile.txt
>         owner: test
>         group: test
>       become: yes
>       become_user: test
>       become_method: su
> ```

> ```
>       copy:
>         content: hello
>         dest: /tmp/testfile.txt
>         owner: test
>         group: test
>       become: yes
> ```

> ```
>       copy:
>         content: hello
>         dest: /tmp/testfile.txt
>         owner: test
>         group: test
>       become_user: test
>       become_method: su
> ```

always getting a message about the password being incorrect. The awkward moment is that test user has no password

What am I doing wrong?

**Updates:**

*Tried this*

[How to achieve sudo su - <user> and run all command in ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38958333/how-to-achieve-sudo-su-user-and-run-all-command-in-ansible) <-- does not work

*Found an answer - it is not possible*

https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/3588/how-do-you-simulate-sudo-su-user-in-ansible

*What is the point?*

to cite from Quora (source: https://www.quora.com/What-is-advantage-of-creating-passwordless-user-in-Linux)

> I presume you mean processes such as a webserver, running as the
> "apache" user with a locked password (shadow entry of '!!').
>
> This is for security, in case a vulnerability is discovered in the
> server code. Prior to the year 2000 or so, it was common for servers
> to run as the root user, particularly as this privilege is required to
> open network sockets on privileged ports (below 1024), such as 53
> (DNS) or 80 (HTTP). As I recall, high-profile breaches of the bind and
> sendmail servers caused developers to re-think this strategy. Since
> then, services are started with root privilege, the socket opened, and
> then privilege is dropped to a non-privileged user ID such as "apache"
> or "named". This needs no password, since it is never intended that
> anyone login. Rather, a process running as root executes a setuid()
> system call to change effective user ID to this user. In the event of
> a security breach, an attacker will be limited to the access lists of
> this user; for instance, a vulnerable CGI script on a webserver would
> be able to access the /tmp directory as the "apache" user, but be
> unable to read /etc/shadow for instance, or to write an extra user
> into /etc/passwd or modify system binaries in /sbin.

Comment: please add your solution in the answer box, don't edit it into the question. :)

Comment: What's the point anyway?  Just become `root`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid what is described in "password not being accepted for `sudo` user with ansible":

```
fatal: [testserver]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Incorrect su password"}
```

You might try using `sudo`, assuming you have [given `test` user `sudo` rights](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-ultimate-guide-to-linux-creating-a-sudo-user/):

```sh
# Debian systems (Ubuntu / Linux Mint / ElementryOS), add users to the sudo group
sudo usermod -aG sudo username

# On RHEL based systems (Fedora / CentOS), add users to the wheel group
sudo usermod -aG wheel username
```

Then:

```
become_user: test
become_method: sudo
```

Laucnhed with:

```
ansible-playbook -i inventory simple_playbook.yml --ask-become-pass
```

And enter the root password